# The space next to the last tabpage is contained in form1 or tabcontrol1

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

In my form1 I have a tabcontrol which fills the form. So,I have created a Graphics.rectangle next to the last tabpage and I want to Handle the Click on this "rectangle".. The question is: I have to use Tabcontrol1.mousedown OR Form1.mousedown ??

Comment: If TabControl fills the page, you won't be able to use the Form1.MouseDown since it won't receive any mouse messages.  What is not clear to us is how you created your Graphics.Rectangle.  We need to see some relevant code.

Comment: The answer is probably that neither will work - if you are talking about a gap after the tab header or thumb.  The area is part of the TabControl client area, but since there is nothing there, it may not report events.

Comment: @Plutonix this is actually my main problem, as I have tried them both but neither works :/ Also, buttons are not allowed to be placed next to the tabs, (it would be much easier with a button)

Answer (score 1):

Since the TabControl's dock is set to fill, it is covering the entire form. So you would need to handle

```
TabControl1_MouseDown(sender as Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles TabControl1.MouseDown
'code here
End Sub
```

Where the comment is, you would then check to see if the mouse is within the bounds of your created rectangle.

Unfortunately, I do not know how you are creating the rectangle, so I can't really provide any more information.

Comment: Actually, I know how to check if user clicks inside the bounds with if condition.. Like:                                           

if e.X <= … AndAlso
e.X >= … AndAlso
e.Y <= … AndAlso
e.Y >= … then
'code here.. End If         .Am I right?